# appending to a tar file in a loop

Tags: linux, shell

I have a directory, that has a maybe 6 files.

```
team1_t444444_jill.csv
team1_t444444_jill.csv
team1_t444444_jill.csv
team1_t999999_jill.csv
team1_t999999_jill.csv
team1_t111111_jill.csv
team1_t111111_jill.csv
```

I want to be able to tar each of the files based on their t number, so t444444 should have it's own tar file with all the corresponding csv's. t999999 should then have its own and so on... a total of three tar files should be created dynamically

```
for file in $bad_dir/*.csv; do
  fbname=`basename "$file" | cut -d. -f1`  #takes the pathfile off, only shows xxx_tyyyyy_zzz.csv
  t_name=$(echo "$fbname" | cut -d_ -f2)   #takes the remaning stuff off, only shows tyyyyy

  #now i am stuck on how to create a tar file and send email
  taredFile = ??? #no idea how to implement

  (cat home/files/hello.txt; uuencode $taredFile $taredFile) | mail -s "Failed Files" $t_name@hotmail.com
```

Comment: Have you tried anything for the tar command you need? Also realize that you are going to loop over the same `t_name` multiple times here so you need to be careful not to send the email more than once (presumably).

Comment: this is true, don't want to send email more than once, i am not sure how to use tar? would i update or append the tar file... create a tar file and maybe delete it untill i see the next unique t name?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest edit of your script that should do what you want is likely something like this.

```
for file in $bad_dir/*.csv; do
  fbname=`basename "$file" | cut -d. -f1`  #takes the pathfile off, only shows xxx_tyyyyy_zzz.csv
  t_name=$(echo "$fbname" | cut -d_ -f2)   #takes the remaning stuff off, only shows tyyyyy

  tarFile=$t_name-combined.tar
  if [ ! -f "$tarFile" ]; then
      tar -cf "$tarFile" *_${t_name}_*.csv
      { cat home/files/hello.txt; uuencode $tarFile $tarFile; } | mail -s "Failed Files" $t_name@hotmail.com
  fi
done
```

Use a tar file name based on the unique bit of the input file names. Then check for that file existing before creating it and sending email (protects against creating the file more than once and sending email more than once).

Use the fact that the files are globbable to get tar to archive them all from the first one we see.

You'll also notice that I replaced `(commands)` with `{ commands; }` in the pipeline. The `()` force a sub-shell but so does the pipe itself so there's no reason (in this case) to force an *extra* sub-shell manually just for the grouping effect.

Comment: wow this is awesome, i will test it out and let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
for i in `find  | cut -d. -f2 | cut -d_ -f1,2 | sort | uniq`;
do
 tar -zvcf $i.tgz $i*
 # mail the $i.tgz file
done
```

Take a look on my run:

```
$ for i in `find  | cut -d. -f2 | cut -d_ -f1,2 | sort | uniq`; do tar -zvcf $i.tgz $i*; done
team1_t111111_jill.csv
team1_t111111_jxx.csv
team1_t111111.tgz
team1_t444444_j123.csv
team1_t444444_j444.csv
team1_t444444_jill.csv
team1_t444444.tgz
team1_t999999_jill.csv
team1_t999999_jilx.csv
team1_t999999.tgz

ubuntu@ubuntu1504:/tmp/foo$ ls
team1_t111111_jill.csv  team1_t111111.tgz       team1_t444444_j444.csv  team1_t444444.tgz       team1_t999999_jilx.csv
team1_t111111_jxx.csv   team1_t444444_j123.csv  team1_t444444_jill.csv  team1_t999999_jill.csv  team1_t999999.tgz
```

Comment: [Don't parse the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You took what was a safe loop and made it entirely unsafe instead.

Comment: Just fixed it! Thanks

Comment: Nope. Still entirely unsafe. It just doesn't use `ls` anymore. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for more.

Comment: I don't think that any of these cases applies here, right?

Comment: Assuming you know what input files you are going to find is a bad idea and will cause problems when your input changes. Being safe is just a better default position (and usually not much harder). You could do this same thing with a `while`/`read` loop over the file names safely.